# Viewport meta tag with semi-responsive site

Tags: html, responsive-design

I have a fixed-width site (980px) where we have been asked to remove the right hand sidebar on smaller devices. (Devices where the screen size is less than 768px, say.)

This means that effectively, we're running two fixed-width sites from the same codebase.

We're using the following meta tag in the site:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

The problem is that on larger tablets, we're seeing the full site (as we should), but zoomed in. (Because the tablet is considering full width to be - say - 768px and is zooming accordingly.)

I cannot set width to be a fixed size:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=980,initial-scale=1">
```

...because smaller devices will then zoom out too far.

Is there any workaround that will fix the zoom-level properly for all devices?

(n.b. I am aware that the basic idea is wrong here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I've managed to get this up and running.

Start by setting width=device-width to ensure that the correct "responsive" version loads. Give the metatag an ID so that we can easily grab it later.

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
```

Then, we want to check the screen size so that we can force the width and zoom to right size:

```
(function($){
    $(function(){
        if (window.matchMedia !== undefined) {
            var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)");
            if (mq.matches) {
                $('#viewport').attr('content', 'width=767');
            }else{
                $('#viewport').attr('content', 'width=980');
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I noticed that setting initial-scale in any way broke zoom.

Note that I'm using [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia) here, which although not fully supported, is fine for my purposes. If you need to support a greater percentage of users, you might consider using [Modernizr.mq](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq) instead.